# LiDAR point cloud to 3D model of street

Tags: 3d, lidar, 3d-analyst, 3d-map, 3d-model

I am looking for a way to convert point cloud collected through a [Riegl](http://riegl.com/) LiDAR scanner to a perfect 3D model of a town.

The sample data is from vehicle mounted scanner, but final data is going to be from aerial and vehicle mounted scanners.

The final 3D model of the town is supposed to be used as a terrain for a FPS (first person shooting) video game.

I am not sure where to begin. I have some sample data. The data is available in the following formats:

1. SDW
2. SDC
3. LAS/LAZ

Is it even possible? The point cloud has color information. The sample point cloud that I have has RGB values for each point, but as far as I have tested the City Engine doesn't work with point clouds, it needs meshes, am I right?

For classes, can't I use height function for the points, to define all points at a certain height to be the ground, and everything higher buildings? I need to take the cars out anyway, so maybe I can take the trees out too, then I have just two classes, the ground class and the not ground class (the buildings).

Comment: How are you going to display the data when you're finished? as a fly through, static pictures (snapshots), online?? I've seen some very good models from LiDAR but the results are only as good as your points... what is your nominal pulses per square metre? I'm not familiar with Riegl data, is it Aerial, static or vehicle mounted?

Comment: I have updated some information, but for the sample data, I dont have the information nominal pulses per m2

Comment: Esri City Engine is a good product, ENVI LiDAR also has this capability. There are some very good 3d libraries that could be of use - but **none of them are free**. Euclideon http://www.euclideon.com/ is an exceptional product with an API... possibly the pick of the bunch. To use this data in a first person perspective what format does the interpolated data need to be in? You're not going to supply LAS are you? Examples that I have seen interpolate to facets then wrap photos (textures) around the 3d polygons.

Comment: This is not possible in ArcGIS with 3D Analyst. As @MichaelMiles-Stimson suggests, perhaps the city engine may work. Lidar cloud alone wont be enough.  You will need a way to classify points as being a "member" of this or that structure;  there are Lidar technologies that also record RGB values with each point - something like that may be helpful but I beleive this data is quite expensive. with just a cloud and whatever default Lidar classes you will have at your disposal, you may heave to a lot of manual modelling, classifying, QAQC.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by expensive, are you talking about time needed to perform the scan or the cost of scanner? 
p.s. please see the added information in the questions :)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138611/how-to-merge-a-shape-file-to-geotiff-image-using-r

plz review this